# Keep the ads div fully in view

Tags: javascript, css

I've got to (unfortunately) put our ads onto our website. They're positioned down the right hand side of the page, outside of the content area.

When the screen width gets smaller, because it's positioned outside of the content they get cut off by the browser. I can offset everything by putting `left: -someValuepx`, which moves everything over.

Rather than having to put in lots and lots of media queries to keep slightly moving it over, is this something I can do in Javascript, to automatically keep them in the view? Ideally I'd like a function that I can run on page load, and then on the window resize event.

Here's a jsfiddle of the CSS at the moment. Edit the #container left attr to move the content.

And here's the code (as I believe it's required if you link to jsfiddle?)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="ads">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width:500px;
    min-height:100px;
    background-color: firebrick;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    left:-50px;
}

#ads {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-170px;
    width:160px;
    min-height:100px;
}
#content {
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
    min-height:100px;
}
```

Comment: You could use fixed positioning if you need them always in view

Comment: Would that not mean thought that when the view gets smaller they cover up the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a pure css solution, if you change your div structure to the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="padding">
        <div id="ads"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You are able to use the following styles:

```
#container {
    width:670px;
    min-height:100px;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
}

#container > .padding {
    margin-right:170px;
    background-color: firebrick;
}

#ads {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:160px;
    min-height:100px;
}

#content {
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
    min-height:100px;
}

@media (max-width:670px) /*this is the width of the container*/
{
    #container {float:right;}
}
```

And this will keep your adds in view when the viewport is resized

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dZbyW/10/)

Comment: Very nice :), I'll give this a go now putting it in my site and report back.

Comment: Good stuff, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is to create a function in JS that gets executed one time when the document is loaded and also when you resize.

This function should add a class (ie: hidden) to the the ads. you want to hide, and with CSS, give the right properties. Just addClass and removeClass, depending on the situation, should make the trick.

Example:

```
#ads { // normal values that makes the content of the ads visible } 

#ads .hide  { // offset values to hide the ads }
```

This way, you keep behavior & presentation separated.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

In your html markup, you have both content and the ads inside a container. The problem is that the content takes all space of the container, and the ads are positioned outside of it.

Just make the container wide enaugh to hold both content and the ads, then position them appropriately. Make one break point on the width of content+ads (660px), where you would position the ads below the content, and give the container its current width (500px).